# How do you get the indices of a Numpy slice with a step?

Tags: python, numpy

**Original Question (with stupid example):** e.g my question is simple, how do you get the index positions of a slice with step, in Numpy. See example below where you can use np.nonzero on a slice but include a step and you don't. Is there another option

```
import numpy as np
d = np.hstack([np.arange(6), np.arange(6), np.arange(6)])
step = 6

np.nonzero(d[0:-1])
Out[45]: (array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16]),)

In [46]: np.nonzero(d[0:-1:step])
Out[46]: (array([], dtype=int64),)
`
```

**Question I should have asked.**

How do you get the indices of a slice with a step in Numpy.
e.g

```
import numpy as np
d = np.hstack([np.arange(6), np.arange(6), np.arange(6)])
step = 6

#The indices of d[0:-1:step] would be:
array([ 0,  6, 12])
```

Comment: But isn't this because your step is equal to the positions where 0 resides? Because `d[0:-1:step]` returns
`Out[58]: array([0, 0, 0])` So this is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.nonzero` works with a step arg, it's just your step arg matches the indices where there are no non-zero values:

```
In[59]:
d[0:-1:step]

Out[59]: array([0, 0, 0])
```

For instance if your step arg was `5` then it works as expected:

```
In[60]:
d[0:-1:5]

Out[60]: array([0, 5, 4, 3])

In[61]:
np.nonzero(d[0:-1:5])

Out[61]: (array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64),)
```

**Update**

If you just want the indices from a slice then you can just apply the slice to a range:

```
In[72]:
np.arange(len(d))[0:-1:step]

Out[72]: array([ 0,  6, 12])
```

Or just do `arange` and pass the length and step params:

```
In[73]:
np.arange(0, len(d), step)

Out[73]: array([ 0,  6, 12])
```

**Update 2**

Thanks to @Divakar (the numpy master) you can use [`r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to convert slice notation to an array, plus this is less typing:

```
In[79]:
np.r_[:len(d):step]

Out[79]: array([ 0,  6, 12])
```

Comment: If you want to go fancy/stay close to slicing notation : `np.r_[:len(d):step]`.

Comment: @Divakar sure that's a much cleaner way, will update, thanks

Comment: That's amazing.

Answer (score 0):

if your `step=6` your `numpy array d` will act like

```
step = 6
print((d[0:-1:step]))
output:[0 0 0]
```

because

```
d = np.hstack([np.arange(6), np.arange(6), np.arange(6)])
print(d)
output: [0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

so `step=6`

```
np.nonzero(d[0:-1:step])
output: (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: This is the same as my answer

Comment: explanation is difference which can help the OP